# Install Foundation 5 in ember-cli

Tags: css, ember.js, sass, compass-sass

I am fairly new to ember and very new to the build tools. I am currently using the usual foundation install with the foundation cli and compass to compile my css, this is a bit of a pain and is very bad for working on a team. I thought it would be better to install the files with bower and use `ember-cli-compass-compiler` as stated in the docs but its not working as expected. I would like to have the `app.scss` file in the `app/styles` directory and import all the required foundation components within that file. I would also like to keep the `_settings.scss` component within the `app/styles` directory so it can be easily shared.

E.g

```
@import "settings";
@import "vendor/foundation/scss/foundation";
```

However this gives me the error `File to import not found or unreadable: vendor/foundation/scss/foundation.`

I can assure you that the foundation.scss file in the vendor directory does exist. I have also tried importing the file using `app.import()` in the `Brocfile.js` but with no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use the .scss version of Foundation, you should first configure your project to use broccoli-sass with:

```
npm install --save-dev broccoli-sass
```

and then rename your `app/styles/app.css` to `app/styles/app.scss`.

Then you can install Foundation using Bower with:

```
bower install --save-dev foundation
```

Now, inside your `app/styles/app.scss`, you can import the Foundation styles with:

```
@import 'bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize';
@import 'bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation';
```

Comment: Thank-you! That worked perfectly. To get the settings to work from within the `app/styles` directory I had to edit the import of the functions component on line 41 to the full vendor directory.

Comment: ember-cli recently switched from `vendor` to `bower_components` to install bower components. Therefor the path for `@import` should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @bazzel. I'm not sure why your edit suggestion was being rejected. I updated the original answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just recently released ember-cli addon for foundation

Here: https://github.com/artificialio/ember-cli-foundation-sass

and here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-foundation-sass.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. If that is the case for any other developers then this answer might help.

First, install `ember-cli-sass` addon

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-sass
```

Next, install foundation

```
bower install --save-dev foundation
```

At this point you might want to rename your `app.css` to either `app.scss` or `app.sass`.

Next, tell ember cli to include the foundation Sass files just installed in the asset pipeline building process. Add the following code in `ember-cli-build.js`

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [
      'bower_components/foundation/scss'
    ]
  }
});
```

In your `app.scss` file, import foundation using the following line of code

```
@import 'foundation';
```

If you do not want to import all of foundation but bits of it, then you can do so by importing the appropriate component e.g. `@import 'foundation/fuctions'`

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me well! Just install following package,

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-foundation
```